# Creating autosys job

Tags: autosys

We have a autosys box job let say A which contain 3 child jobs(B,c and D).

We have created a separate autosys job E , which will send mail if B and C fails.
We need to have condition where once  E executed successfully..the autosys job A needs to be restarted again.

Note - the box job is scheduled to run daily at particular time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. What have you tried? Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful to you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please share JIL for the jobs

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a sample code that would be good.
Base on what I understood. You want to run job A if E is executed successfully.
for that you need to add below line in your code (Jil file or using GUI)

```
/*-----job E if I had code available, would have changed and shared -----------*/

condition: success(E)
or 
condition: s(E)
```

This job will execute immediately after job E is successful

Answer (score 0):

Condition for job "E".

```
condition: f(B) OR FAILURE(C)
condition: FAILURE(B) | f(C)
```

Condition for job "A".

```
condition: s(E)
```

Note: Job name is case sensitive, you can give `f` or `failure` for failure status, `s` or `success` for success status, `OR` or `|` for OR condition & `AND` or `&` for AND condition. You can use `d` or `done` when you want your job to start even if predecessor job completed with SUCCESS, FAILURE or TERMINATED state.